# creating a macro to separate data

Tags: excel, vba

HI I am new to using excel and only have a basic knowledge in designing macros. I want to be able to design a macro that can separate different invoice details depending on the company unique id into a separate sheet. only problem there is two or three rows that need to be moved together. How would I go about doing this?

For example:

[image]

Here is a sample picture of the data. what i want to do is copy the H and N in rows 1 and 2 deepening on the value in row D

Comment: Please add images and examples of where the data is located, named ranges, and what you've tried already.  If the data is static then just record a macro of you selecting the data and copy and paste.

Comment: I have edited my question and added a picture, i hope it make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your testing for something like 'is value > 25'

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cntr As Integer
    cntr = 1

    Set rng = [A1:A5]
    dat = rng  ' dat is now array (1 to 5, 1 to 1)
    For i = LBound(dat, 1) To UBound(dat, 1)
        If rng(i, 1).Offset(0, 3).Value > 25 Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & cntr).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
            cntr = cntr + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```